# How to make a ListView in android with images in it?

Tags: java, android, json, viewflipper

I need an organized way to organize my app and buttons are starting to look sloppy in my opinion. Below is my code. I have the XML set up to a List View. Not sure if it is right or not.

```
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my java code. I didn't change it yet,, except for the imports from previous attempts to do this.
package com.apw.listview.test;

```
import android.app.*; 
import android.os.*; 
import android.view.*; 
import android.widget.*; 
import android.content.*; 

public class Species extends Activity
{ 


/** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.species);

} 



}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lazy load of images in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use a ListView is using an Adapter, see the tutorial there for example : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html